# Why cant I declare a generic base class that also inherits?

Tags: c#, oop

I really want to do this...

```
 public class BaseController<T> where T : IPageModel, Controller
```

But visual studio doesnt like it. Controller is a class from the MVC. and I page model ensures acess to some model stuff. Have I got the syntax wrong?

Comment: What's supposed to inherit/implement what? `BaseController<T>` to `Controller` and `T` to `IPageModel`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
public class BaseController<T>: Controller where T : IPageModel
```

Everything that follows the `where` keyword is considered as generic constraint declaration. In your case you want to have your class derive from `Controller`, so you start by indicating this first and at the end you specify the generic constraints.

Now your actual controllers could derive from this base controller:

```
public class FooController: BaseController<Foo>
{
    ...
}
```

where obviously `Foo` must implement `IPageModel` which is enforced by the generic constraint:

```
public class Foo: IPageModel
{
    ...
}
```